# Chat's compose window should warn if text is too long

Tags: feature-request, status-completed, chat

Currently there is no indication if message limit is reached. Instead on posting get told and offered retry/cancel.

The only viable approach is to copy somewhere else, cancel and compose as multiple messages.

Better to have some indication of space available in the compose window.

Comment: [status-agreed]

Comment: @balpha: I told you to not have a limit. Why does no one listen to me?

Comment: @Web: What have you said?

Comment: @Lady: I have said that small size limits are not something that you want this chat software to have. Big limits, sure, but not small ones. What you really want is a way to collapse big messages so they don't interrupt the flow of the conversation but you still want to allow them.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

We're thinking a small `<div>` overlay will appear while you're typing and give you a countdown -- but **only when you've typed "too much"**